# How to tell javascript "any number bigger than" on a ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, spring, ternary-operator, gatsby

I need to establish a ternary operator with a condition: whenever the URL is /index/ plus any number bigger than "1" does X.

I tried this (the string with the "to" propriety:

```
<Spring
    from={{ height: location.pathname === '/' ? '0vh' : '0vh' }}
    to={{ height: (location.pathname === '/' || location.pathname === '/index/' + (>= 2) ) ? '36vh' : '0vh' }}
>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. 
It's for a pagination problem (I don't know how much pages will be created).

Comment: This has nothing to do with the conditional operator. It has to do with matching a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the conditional operator. It has to do with matching a string. If you want to match `location.pathname` to `/index/n` where `n` must be greater than 1, you'll probably want a regular expression:

```
/\/index\/(?:[2-9]|\d{2,})/.test(location.pathname)
```

The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group. The `[2-9]|\d{2,}` is an alternation, matching either `[2-9]` or `\d{2,}`. `[2-9]` matches any digit from 2 to 9, inclusive. `\d{2,}` matches two or more digits.

In context:

```
<Spring
    from={{ height: location.pathname === '/' ? '0vh' : '0vh' }}
    to={{ height: (location.pathname === '/' || /\/index\/(?:[2-9]|\d{2,})/.test(location.pathname) ) ? '36vh' : '0vh' }}
>
```

Comment: Sorry how can I add this to the string? Is this ok? ```... location.pathname === '/' || location.pathname === `${/\/index\/(?:[2-9]|\d{2,})/` ? ...``` I'm trying different combinations but they do not work

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. I still don't get the use of `.test(location.pathname)`, is it necessary whenever I use a regular expression? instead of using location.pathname on the initial condition (?)

Comment: @Santiago - `test` is a method of regular expressions that's usually the best choice if you don't need the match object. You *could* do `location.pathname.match(/.../) != null`, but it creates a match object that you're only going to use for a yes/no decision. `test` returns a boolean instead.